SQL Server Permissions to synonym and underlying objects
I have DatabaseX_2024 and DatabaseY on same SQL Server. My app works with DatabaseY but need some data from DatabaseX_2024. Because name of DatabaseX_2024 is changing (will be DatabaseX_2025 next year), I made synonym in DatabaseY. When name of DatabaseX_2024 changes, I have to recreate synonym in DatabaseY and change name of targeting DB to DatabaseX_2025, and my app will works without changes within.  So far, so good.
What I found is that I have to grant permissions for users in DatabaseY not only for synonym (in same DB), but also on underlying objects in DatabaseX_2024. Not ideal solution, but if it have to be like that, let it be.
Problem (or strange behaviour) is this:
If I pick existing user from DatabaseX_2024 and add them to DatabaseY and grant him permission to synonym, everything works as expected. But if I create new user in DatabaseY, grant him permission to synonym and after that add him to DatabaseX_2024 and grant him permissions to underlying objects in that DB, that new user can NOT use synonym because DatabaseX_2024 refuses it ("does not have permission"!?) unless that new user is owner of schema to which synonym belongs in DatabaseY!?!?
As I can have only one owner of schema, it means that I can NOT add multiple users in DatabaseY which will use synonym!?
Where is the problem and what is solution for this?
NOTE: SQL Server uses Integrated Security (domain usernames).
I set that new user as owner of schema, but there must be better solution...

"Because name of DatabaseX_2024 is changing (will be DatabaseX_2025 next year)" This sounds like the real problem. Changing your database name, or making a new database each year (with a new name) constantly is a obvious sign of a design flaw. "there must be better solution..." Fixing your design.

"also on underlying objects in DatabaseX_2024" Correct, USERs are created at database level, so a USER in DatabaseY won't have access to data in DatabaseX unless the LOGIN that the USER is mapped to also has a USER in the other database with the relevant permissions. There are some features you can use to avoid explicit permissions, such as database chaining (comes with a wealth of caveats) and signed objects.

"But if I create new user in DatabaseY, grant him permission to synonym and after that add him to DatabaseX_2024 and grant him permissions to underlying objects in that DB, that new user can NOT use synonym because DatabaseX_2024 refuses it unless that new user is owner of schema to which synonym belongs in DatabaseY!?!?!" Then you have done something wrong. Wwnership isn't needed, as demonstrated in this image; the USERs only has SELECT permissions on the TABLE SecurityTest.dbo.MyTable and the SYNONYM SecurityTest2.dbo.MyTable.
